# How to give values ​to a Realm List <Double>?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

How to give values ​​to a Realm List ?
I've created a second class for Double values, but I don't know if it's okay to do that.
I tried to do it like this but it gives me two errors:

Cannot find 'a' in scope

Cannot find 'b' in scope

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Man: Object {
    @Persisted var _id: String?
    @Persisted var date: Int64?
    @Persisted var values: List<Pressure?>
}

class Pressure: Object {
    @Persisted var a: Double?
    @Persisted var b: Double?
}

let realm = try! Realm.init()
let man = Man.init()

man._id = generateRandom(size: 20)
man.date = Date().timestamp
man.values = Pressure(value: [a: 2.47635, b: 8.82763])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with the code in the question. First, I will rename the classes for readability. `Man` and `man` look very similar so I renamed the `Man` class as `ManClass` and `Pressure` to `PressureClass`

Here are a few things

**1) Don't do this**

```
let realm = try! Realm.init()
```

do this (see [Configure and Open a Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/configure-and-open-a-realm/#open-a-default-realm-or-realm-at-a-file-url))

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

**2) there is no generateRandom function**

```
man._id = generateRandom(size: 20)
```

if you want to create a "random" id, it's typically done with a UUID or preferably an ObjectID

```
@Persisted var asda = UUID().uuidString
```

or

```
@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId //YAY!
```

When the object is instatiated, that property is populated which eliminates the need to populate it manually. e.g. you don't need this

```
man._id = generateRandom(size: 20)
```

**3) There is no timestamp function**, and the `.date` property is `Date`, not a timestamp

```
man.date = Date()
```

**4) When assigning values to properties, the property names have to be within quotes; "a" and "b" for example.**  Also, this is not appending a value to a list, so this doesn't work

```
man.values = Pressure(value: [a: 2.47635, b: 8.82763])
```

This does

```
man.values = PressureClass(value: ["a": 2.47635, "b": 8.82763])
```

you can also do this

```
let p = PressureClass()
p.a = 2.4
p.b = 8.8
```

and then

```
man.values.append(p) //add a single value to a `List`
```

**OR** you can update the PressureClass with a convenience init instead of dealing with this `["a": 2.47635, "b": 8.82763]`

```
class PressureClass: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var a: Double?
    @Persisted var b: Double?

    convenience init(a: Double, b:Double) {
        self.init()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

and then go nuts adding values

```
let x = PressureClass(a: 2.4, b: 8.8)
let y = PressureClass(a: 1.5, b: 2.6)
let z = PressureClass(a: 9.5, b: 6.2)

man.values.append(objectsIn: [x, y, z]) //add multiple values to a `List`
```